# Retrieving specific numbers from a string

Tags: c#, properties, struct, set, accessor

I'm implementing complex numbers structure and I want users to have a possibility to insert values into *Re* and *Im* fields via property *Geo*, which is a geometric interpretation of a complex number e.g. (5,-3).

```
struct Cplx
{
    public double Re;
    public double Im;

    public string Geo
    {
        get
        {
            return "(" + Re + "," + Im + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make the *set* accessor. Basically, I want to retrieve numbers x, y from (x,y) string so I can put them into double fields.

Comment: Does it really have to be a setter? Can't it be a method?

Comment: ... or better two setters, one for every component. That way you make sure that the user _understands_ what they are entering. A string might be poorly formated.

Comment: It might be, but isn't this what properties are for?
(I'm not trying to be mean - I'm literally asking)

Comment: @lavsprat, you're totally right, properties would work much better. It's still early here, I guess...

Comment: @AndreiV I'm just not a fan of string properties setting integer/float fields.

Comment: @S_F, my string reference was related to a string setter like the one in Ondrej Janacek's answer. It might not be intuitive enough. Float fields would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse `value` which contains input like (5,-3), remove parenthesis and spaces and convert values to double.

```
set
{
    var input = value.Split(new[] { '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Re = Convert.ToDouble(input[0]);
    Im = Convert.ToDouble(input[1]);
}
```

Just a note, structs should be immutable, so I would advise to pass values to a constructor instead of setting them via a property. This would be a proper way to do it

```
struct Cplx
{
    public readonly double Re;
    public readonly double Im;

    public string Geo
    {
        get
        {
            return "(" + Re + "," + Im + ")";
        }
    }

    public Cplx(double re, double im)
    {
        Re = re;
        Im = im;
    }

    public Cplx(string cplx)
    {
        var input = cplx.Split(new[] { '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Re = Convert.ToDouble(input[0]);
        Im = Convert.ToDouble(input[1]);
    }
}
```